# How much gunpowder (or other materials) it would be required to accelerate 4mm Tungsten Sphere to 50 km/s?

Tags: physics, hard-science, guns

I don't understand much about physics and ballistics, so I hope I don't make too many incorrect assumptions here.

So, I just saw [this video](https://youtu.be/mFdOgkllUvs) where a 4 mm tungsten sphere hits a 85 mm steel armor, and it hits the target with so much force it simply melts the steel. No deformation or fragmentation, just melts like butter.

So, how much gunpowder (the "nitropowder" used on guns, or cordite and so on) it would be required to accelerate this projectile (a 4 mm tungsten sphere) to 50 km/s?
Or at this point, it would be "easier" to just use a small charge of C4?

Well, I would guess that this is not very logistically efficient, since you would be able to shot a lot of regular sized projectiles with the same amount of gunpowder.

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve (super-) hypervelocity with the wrong method. Gunpowder, or nitropowder, are chemical means. There have been hypervelocity experiments yielding similar results your video shows, achieved with only 2.5 km/s (max 8.5), actually 20 times less than your requirement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity Shooting high velocity projectiles is achieved using a Light gas gun in a laboratory, a huge apparatus, comparable to a super air gun https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun

Comment: A quick note: it is considered best practice to wait between 24-48 hours before accepting an answer.

Comment: It seems likely that the video does not accurately describe what it depicts. The most powerful light gas guns fire small projectiles around 7 km/s. The US Navy's experimental railguns only achieve about 2.5 km/s, albeit with much larger projectiles.

Comment: This is off-topic for this stack. It should be asked on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @computercarguy This question works just fine on WB.SE.  Since the OP does not even know what propellent he should be using, this is not purely a physics question.  WB.SE works a lot with answering questions about bleeding-edge, near future, and theoretical technologies; so, the familiarity of this community with what propellants should or could be used may be more helpful than one that specializes at crunching the numbers.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, the propellant is an incidental factoid and still not relevant to worldbuilding. If the OP was asking about a fictional material then it could be on-topic, but this is completely based in reality and physics. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/questions-about-real-world-effect-of-real-world-bullets-appropriate-on-wb

Comment: @computercarguy The propellant is far from incidental (in a world building sense),  It determines if your weapon is a riffle, a shoulder carried anti material weapon like a Law, or something you need a tank or battleship to carry. Or if chemical explosives wont work, knowing about various forms of coil guns or light air guns or scram jet bullets may become necessary... physics.SE tells you how much C4 to use, WB.SE tells you if C4 is even a good way to go

Comment: @Nosajimiki, physics.SE would also be able to tell us if C4  or a coil gun is required. It would also tell us if it's even theoretically possible, due to the forces involved in the firing chamber or how long the coil gun would need to be. IFF physics said it was impossible, this stack could take over, but we don't know that from the Q right now. The A by L. Dutch does pure physics to show it might not be possible by physics and physics.SE would likely be able to actually answer that rather than just guess.

Comment: @computercarguy My point is that this question has an impact on how the OP designs his setting.  That makes this question 100% on-topic for this stack as sphennings pointed out in the meta discussion you linked.  Just because a question CAN be answered on another stack does not make it off topic for this one.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, my point is that the OP hasn't told us what their setting is. We don't know that this is a worldbuilding question. As it stands, it's pure physics. From that same answer you mention: "What matters for this site is that the worldbuilding context is made apparent to us." That context hasn't been made apparent, so it's off-topic. It doesn't even matter that it can be answered on another stack, but it's good that another stack can answer it and likely do a better job of it.

Comment: @computercarguy I understand your reasoning, and disagree with it 100%.  See the answer I just added to your cited meta question. It explains several reasons why this can not be an off topic question, but the short answer is: this is a World Building site, the de facto assumption is that questions are about World Building unless they say it is not.  Not the other way arround.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, I don't agree with your answer, and it doesn't apply to this question since 'clearly states "I am working on a sci-fi thing"', to quote from your answer, which this question doesn't. Also, reference the "expectations and standards" section of https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate. This Q fails all 3 of those bullet points. Watching a video isn't research on what the video shows.

Comment: @computercarguy You are selectively referencing these posts while ignoring things they say like '..."Shouldn’t we tell people to post orbital mechanics questions on Physics, or Astronomy?!" Well... Maybe, but it should be noted in most cases the author chooses the site where they would like to post the question, this means they intentionally chose Worldbuilding over another site and that should be respected.' or '...but there is no reason to even require that much, or else every single question of WB.SE would be required to explain "I am working on a story" to be on topic'

Comment: @Nosajimiki, and you are selectively forgetting that these still all state that a requirement is made for the Q to state they are working on a story. But rules like that don't matter because of how subjectively they are applied. It just proves I (and probably no one) will never understand any of the rules of any stack here. I never wanted to take any kind of hard stance on this Q, I just wanted to apply rules evenly and objectively. But that doesn't matter. I'm done arguing. Every time I have one of these "rules are subjectively applied" arguments I care less and less about every SE forum.

Comment: As for the 3 bullet points you bring up, for bullet #1, he explains that he is trying to design a high velocity armor penetrating weapon.  That is enough context to understand the purpose of the question. The OP cited a video on high velocity tungsten penetrators' and has a baseline understanding of various propellants, and is stuck there, this shows a cursory amount of research.

Comment: Getting from where he is to where he is trying to be requires a deep understanding of many different types of ballistic techniques which he would not get from a cursory amount of research, so that checks bullet #2.  For Bullet #3, he gives the exact speed and mass of the slug, so that one is also checked.

Comment: @computercarguy This is only expressly stated in only 1 of your citations, and is itself questionable in context of the precedent set by the majority of questions asked on this site.  Pick any random 10 questions with positive scores and see how many expressly say "I am writing a story" This is a thing we simply infer when we read most questions on here, because that is the whole point of this site.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, in most questions, it's obvious they are writing a story because of how they ask a question. This one doesn't say anything other than asking a pure physics question. And you must be looking at a different question than I am, because this one doesn't say anything about research other than the video the question is about and it doesn't say anything about designing a weapon or armor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your bullet to go from standing still to leaving the muzzle at 50 km/s, it means that it must receive an energy of $E=1/2 m_b \cdot v^2$.

The velocity is given, the mass of a 4 mm radius tungsten ball is given by its volume, $2.68 \cdot 10^{-4}\ dm^3$, times its density, 19250 $g/dm^3$, resulting in 5.16 g. Thus we are looking at a kinetic energy of E = 6450 kJ.

According to [Wolphram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6450000+J+to+kton), that't the amount of energy released by the 1.5 kilograms of TNT, which occupies about 1 $dm^3$.

This is a first, rough approximation. Once you take into account losses due to imperfect combustion, friction in the muzzle, imperfect sealing and so on, that figure goes very quickly up to the point of becoming unrealistic.

Escape velocity figures by means of explosions can be achieved with [nuclear explosion](https://gizmodo.com/no-a-nuclear-explosion-did-not-launch-a-manhole-cover-1715340946)s, but there you will need to deal with how to make the "bullet" survive the explosion itself, and the massive drag with the atmosphere.

Comment: Worse, expansion in the chamber and bore as the projectile travels introduces huge pressure losses.  Google "pump gun" to see a way this has been approached, once in an attempt to shell faraway targets, and once (ostensibly) in an attempt to shoot into space.

Comment: Blast waves move at a maximum speed much lower than 50 km/s. It should be impossible under normal circumstances to shoot a projectile any faster than about 8 km/s using a cannon-like weapon.

Comment: I don't understand the 'muzzle' bit. Isn't all of the energy transferred to the shot at the time of the initial explosion? The only purpose of a long muzzle is to provide greater accuracy in the trajectory. Since the velocity of the shot does not depend on the blast wave itself, it can certainly travel faster than the blast wave. The Mythbusters high speed videos of explosions clearly show objects traveling ahead of and faster than the blast wave, and there is no muzzle.

Comment: @rytan451 is correct. Traditional guns have an absolute max speed as determined by gas expansion speed. To shoot faster still using chemical propellants, you would need to lower the pressure in the barrel to a vacuum.

Comment: *"You want your bullet to go from standing still to leaving the muzzle at 50 km/s, it means that it must"* be propelled by a propellant in which the speed of sound is not very much slower than 50 km/sec. (Because a gas cannot expand faster than the speed of sound in the gas; even [with nifty tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun) you cannot get more than a few times faster the speed of sound in the gas. And the speed of sound in hydrogen is only about 1.5 km/sec.)

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond A projectile fired through a barrel continues to accelerate as long as the pressure behind it can overcome the pressure in front of it and its friction with the barrel. Longer barrels are *not* intrinsically more accurate. They're only indirectly more accurate because they accelerate the projectile to a higher speed, leading to a flatter trajectory; and because of a longer sight radius, if aimed with traditional iron sights.

Comment: @AlexP - "even with nifty tricks you cannot get more than a few times faster [than] the speed of sound in the gas". A Voitenko compressor can get up to 40km/s using H2; >25x is not what I would consider "a few times faster".

Comment: @TLW: That you very very much. That is a truely nifty device.

Comment: @
Tech Inquisitor
 In a typical scenario, yes. But this is not a typical scenario. I did not make myself clear. What would project the projectile would not be the pressure blast wave, but the shock wave. Shock waves and blast waves are not the same, and shock waves are not limited by the speed of sound  A barrel actually impedes them, but a barrel could provide direction. The trick is to transduce the shock wave energy into projectile velocity. See for instance 
https://physics.info/shock/

Comment: To push on the projectile, at least some of the propellant has to get up to those speeds, and it takes energy to accelerate its mass.  So you'd have something analogous to the rocket equation, depending on barrel geometry and other design factors, and the energy/mass density of the propellant, or something like that.  So the final kinetic energy of the projectile is a pretty distant lower bound once you're pushing this far into the weeds of diminishing returns with velocity so much faster than normal gas-expansion speeds.

Answer (score 12):

You may want to look at the Voitenko compressor. It accelerates a disc, not a ball, and uses high explosives, not gunpowder, but can achieve shock wave velocities of over 40 km $s^{-1}$.

Initially, hydrogen gas is confined in a hemispherical dome covered by a metal plate and with a barrel at the apex of the hemisphere. The projectile seals the barrel. A shaped charge is exploded against the metal plate. Initially, it offers some resistance, allowing pressure to build; then it fails suddenly, compressing the gas behind to approximately $10^5$ atmospheres. The gas propels the projectile along the tube.

An experiment at Ames Research Centre, using a 3cm thick glass tube as the barrel (the barrel does not survive the experiment), produced a shock wave travelling at 67 km $s^{-1}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voitenko_compressor
http://www.islandone.org/LEOBiblio/SPBI134.HTM

Comment: This is defiantly along the right line of thinking, but should be expanded on further with an actual explanation of what a Voitenko compressor is and how it works; otherwise, this is answer is dangerously close to being a "link-only" answer which is against WB.SE's polices.

Comment: Note that this requires high explosives; gunpowder would not be suitable.

Comment: OK, I will expand. As it wasn't strictly what OP was asking for, I didn't want to go into too much detail.

Answer (score 11):

The speed of sound of regular air is 343 m/s. Blast waves move between 4-8 km/s. 50km/s is quite a bit above that. Projectiles fired from cannons can move at most the speed of sound of the propellant gas. I'm not quite sure of the speed of sound of the propellant gas resulting from a C4 or cordite explosion, but I'm pretty sure it's much closer to 8km/s than 50km/s. In short, even using high explosives like C4, it's impossible to move a projectile at 50km/s using a cannon.

However, all is not lost. Using a rocket, you can move faster than that limit, since you're not relying on a blast wave to push you.

A 4mm ball of tungsten has a mass of 5.17g. Military grade solid rocket propellant (which includes RDX, the active ingredient in C4) has a specific impulse of 268 seconds in a vacuum (lower in atmosphere), per Wikipedia.

The rocket equation is:
$$\Delta v = I_{sp}g_0 \ln\frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

Where $\Delta v$ is the desired change in velocity (which is 50 km/s), $I_{sp}$ is the specific impulse (268 seconds), $g_0$ is acceleration due to gravity (9.81), $m_f$ is the dry mass of the rocket (we shall assume it to be the minimum of 5.17g, the mass of the tungsten ball), and $m_0$ is the mass of the rocket including fuel. We're looking for the value of $m_0 - m_f$.

Solving for $m_f$:

$$5\times10^4ms^{-1} = 2.68\times10^2s\times9.81ms^{-2}\ln\left(\frac{m_0g}{5.17g}\right)$$
$$m_0=5.17\times\exp\left(\frac{5\times10^4}{2.63\times10^3}\right)$$

So $m_0 \approx 9.33 \times10^8$ (rounding to 3 significant figures). That means you'd take about 933 thousand kilograms of military grade rocket fuel to accelerate your 5.17 grams of tungsten. This is probably too much to be practical, and this is already assuming conditions extremely favourable to the launch (you're in a vacuum, there's no rocket hull, only the tungsten ball). In practice, you'll probably need a few more times rocket fuel, rendering this concept even less practical.

Comment: Sounds like you'd better consider switching to a rail gun...

Comment: According to a research paper I found (Thermal decomposition of RDX from reactive molecular dynamics), the maximum particle velocity in a computationally simulated RDX detonation was 3 km/s. However, the detonation velocity of C4 is 8 km/s. In any case, it seems unlikely that C4 is even capable of accelerating the tungsten ball to 25 km/s, much less 50 km/s.

Comment: The projectile does not need to carry the propellant with it in a "gun"-type physics problem, so the rocket equation isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Dragongeek, earlier in the answer I explained why a gun could not possibly shoot a tungsten ball at that speed, which is why I'm using a rocket instead.

Comment: @rytan451 Laboratory light-gas guns have shot projectiles at >8 km/s using rather conventional propellants and two-stage solutions have shot projectiles to speeds >11 km/s. Blast waves don't move projectiles down barrels, pressure does, and I suspect that while there is a cap somewhere due to the inertia of the light gas being used, there's still room upwards in the engineering envelope. Also, it's totally possible to accelerate things faster than the blast--famously the nuclear test "Operation Plumbbob" launched a steel plate at an estimated 66 km/s or shaped-charges like AlDante suggests

Comment: *The muzzle velocity of an airgun, firearm, or light-gas gun is limited by, **but not limited to**, the speed of sound in the working fluid* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun#Design_physics.  Also, starting out by pointing out the 343 m/s speed of sound for air at room temperature and pressure seems a bit odd, not really a relevant figure.  It's significantly different at the temperature achieved inside the chamber of a gun as it fires.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of drifting even further away from OP's original intention, a nuclear explosion blew a 900kg steel cover (the "Manhole cover") into the atmosphere at a speed of 66 km $s^{-1}$.

The nuclear device was detonated at the bottom of a 150m borehole, covered by a steel cap. The principle is the same as in a gun. The explosion causes the gas, in this case air, to rapidly expand. Initial resistance by the cover allows pressure to build slightly, then release suddenly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob#Missing_steel_bore_cap

If this is too far off topic, let me know and I will delete the answer.

Comment: Fascinating. If a 900kg steel cover can evaporate underways, maybe a bullet would ? When it's long range..

Answer (score 1):

As Tech Inquisitor mentioned railguns, let's look at how they stack up. A projectile in an electromagnetic railgun will accelerate until the the induced back electromagnetic force is equal to the applied voltage. This is the theoretical limit; in practice the length of the rails determines how long a projectile can accelerate.

If we have arranged our railgun to operate in a vacuum, with no projectile resistance, then the muzzle velocity of the projectile is given by the following equation:

$$v_{muz} = \sqrt{\frac{2DF}{m}}=\sqrt{\frac{2DILB}{m}}=I\sqrt{\frac{2DL\mu_0}{m}}$$
where

- $v_{muz}=$ Muzzle velocity (metres/second)
- $D=$ Length of rails (metres)
- $F=$ Force applied (Newtons)
- $m=$ Mass of projectile (kilograms)
- $I=$ Current through projectile (Ampères)
- $L=$ Width between rails (metres)
- $B=$ Magnetic field strength (Teslas)
- $\mu_0=1.26 \times10^{-6}$ (The magnetic permeability of free space, Henries/metre)

(Equations taken from [here](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/212_fall2003.web.dir/Daniel_Lenord/velocity.html))

So doubling the velocity requires four times the rail length, one quarter of the mass or twice the current.

Current railguns have a projectile mass in the region of 3kg and a muzzle velocity of about 3.5 km $s^{-1}$. Assuming nothing melts, reducing the mass to 5g (a factor of 600) would give a muzzle speed of the order of $3.5 \times \sqrt{600} \approx 86$ km $s^{-1}$.

As the Navy knows this, and chooses a larger projectile with a lower velocity, I think air friction would melt the smaller projectile.

**Comparison of weapon systems**:

| System | Energy |
| --- | --- |
| Naval Surface Warfare Center Dahlgren | 8 MJ |
| University of Texas | 9 MJ |
| BAE Systems | 32 MJ |
| Dahlgren BAE Systems | 33 MJ |
| Rheinmetall 120mm gun | 9 MJ |
| BGM-109 Tomahawk | 3000 MJ |

Comment: If anyone can explain why the table is fine in preview but not when published, I would be grateful.

Comment: In air, tungsten will burn before it melts.  Same end result, though.

Comment: @AlDante I solved the issue.. *forward slashes* are not allowed in these constructs with the old BBC, apparently they never solved that issue. I removed the / between Dahlgren and BAE.

Comment: @Goodies Thank you very much for finding and correcting this.